# Atoi() function not working Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

The Arduino `atoi()` function is not working as expected. The original is 656649, but when converted to a string, it prints 1289. What could be happening? Thanks!

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  String BT1 = "656649"
  Serial.print(" String BT1: ");
  Serial.print(BT1); // OUTPUT: 656649
  char charBuf[50];
  BT1.toCharArray(charBuf, 50) ;
  Serial.print("Char buff: "); // OUTPUT: 656649
  Serial.print(charBuf);
  intBT1 = atoi(charBuf);
  Serial.print(" intBT1: "); //OUTPUT: 1289
  Serial.print(intBT1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the arduino is 16-bit-system. ``atol`` should work and you should use ``long`` or ``(u)int32_t`` for 32-bit-numbers;

Comment: Print out `sizeof(int)`, what do you get?

Comment: 656649 equals 0x000A0509; 0x0509 equals 1289

Comment: does intBT1 have a data type?  Do you intend it to be an int?  Does the process know that?  Since atoi throws no exceptions you may be seeing Undefined Behavior...the process is trying to help you out.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, intBT1 was defined above:   int intBT1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino `int` and '`unsigned int` types are 16-bit values, too small to hold the number you used.  You need a `long` or `unsigned long` type to hold that value; these are 32 bits long in the ATmega (Arduino) architecture.

Many programming problems with the Arduino stem from these different sizes -- as most personal computer are 64-bit these days, it's easy to forget that the microcontrollers at the heart of the Arduino family are Harvard architecture 8-bit machines with 8-bit registers.

Comment: Which means you'll want to use `atol()` or `atoll()` rather than `atoi()`. But note that the `ato*()` functions do no error checking.